# Weird Glitch When Adding Bevel Geometry to 2D Curves

Tags: scripting, bezier-curves, bevel

I have a script where I create curves from a 3D Printing file (GCode File). The curve created looks like this:

[image]

The curve is 2D. When I give it a bevel of 0.1m this happens:

[image]

The problem disappears if I change the curve type to 3D:

[image]

Due to slight differences in curve behavior in 2D and 3D I would rather have a 2D Curve.
I do understand very well that it might be because two points on the curve might be too close to each other. is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: "*I do understand very well that it might be because two points on the curve might be too close to each other.*" So you already know the likely cause of the issue, why not solve it?

Comment: I understand the cause, but I don't have a solution for it.

Comment: The obvious one is eliminating one of the overlapping vertex

Comment: Doing that would make my script inaccurate, although I am thinking along those lines too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be much simpler that I thought. You can achieve the result using geometry nodes.

The top one is the old way, adding bevel to a curve. Bottom one has been done with geometry nodes. Both are 2D curves.
[image]

This is the geometry node tree:
[image]